# Stack and push() function

Tags: c

I'm doing an exercise, and want support about it. The problem is this: I have two structures (1 for the nodes of the stack, 1 for the stack). In the node structure, there is a void* data field.

I've tried to push a value on the stack but, because of void* data instead of simple data, I failed.

This is the code about the structures and the push() function.

```
struct upo_stack_node_s
{
    void *data;
    struct upo_stack_node_s *next; 
};
typedef struct upo_stack_node_s upo_stack_node_t;

struct upo_stack_s
{
    upo_stack_node_t *top;
    size_t size;
};

/*Function for create the stack*/
upo_stack_t upo_stack_create()
{
    upo_stack_t stack = malloc(sizeof(struct upo_stack_s));
    if (stack == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create a stack!\n");
        abort();
    }

    stack->top = NULL;
    stack->size = 0;

    return stack;
}

/*Push() function:*/
void upo_stack_push(upo_stack_t stack, void *data)
{
    /* TO STUDENTS:
    *  Remove the following two lines and put here your implementation
    */     
    upo_stack_node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(struct upo_stack_node_s));
    node->data = data; /*<-- Here's the problem */
    node->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = node;
    ++stack->size;
}

/*Top() function*/
void* upo_stack_top(const upo_stack_t stack)
{
    /* TO STUDENTS:
     *  Remove the following two lines and put here your implementation
     */
    return (void *)(stack->top); //<---
}

/*Function for testing (there are other functions in the code)*/
void test_top()
{
    int value1 = 1;
    int value2 = 2;
    upo_stack_t stack;

    stack = upo_stack_create();

    upo_stack_push(stack, &value1); //<----
    upo_stack_push(stack, &value2); //<----

    assert( upo_stack_top(stack) != NULL );
    assert( *((int*) upo_stack_top(stack)) == value2 ); <-- Here's the error

    upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);

    assert( upo_stack_top(stack) != NULL );
    assert( *((int*) upo_stack_top(stack)) == value1 );

    upo_stack_pop(stack, 0);

    assert( upo_stack_top(stack) == NULL );

    upo_stack_destroy(stack, 0);
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? And show us how you're calling the function

Comment: The fail is that the stored value isn't the value passed. The function is called in this way: int value1 = 1; int value2 = 2; upo_stack_push(stack, &value1);
    upo_stack_push(stack, &value2); The stack is already created

Answer (score 1):

You always have to pass a void pointer. That means if you want to pass a simple value, like 1, what you need to do is, is to allocate an integer value, and pass the pointer to it (as a void pointer).

Thus something like:

```
int x = 4;
upo_stack_push(upo_stack, &x);
```

Of course you have to make sure the int variable x does not go out of scope, otherwise the pointer will point to freed memory, which results in nasty memory problems.

**Update**

It is assumed above, that the void pointer you pass is stored already in memory for the scope of the stack. In case, you want the stack itself to copy the data, you have also to malloc space for that, thus not only mallocing the node, but also mallocing and copy the data type passed. Also to know the size of the data (since it is a void pointer, which is unaware of its type), you have to add an int size parameter to the push function.

For an integer value to be stored, pass it as a pointer, with size: sizeof(int). Than for copying the data structure, use memcpy. This only works for simple types and structures without pointers. If you have to copy structures with pointers (thus you need so called deep-copying), than it is more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is: how can I storage that void* data, passed as a parameter, in the data field of the structure upo_struct_node_s? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, again. I edited the code. Unfortunately, I can't add other parameters. I must do it with that two parameters.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you have to store the actual values (structures or int's) somewhere else, and 'use' them in your stack, so it keeps only the references. So e.g. store all your values in a big array, and let the stack handle the references, but this is maybe not what you want.

Comment: Thanks again. Another question: in void* data I must store the value or the address of the value, because it's a pointer and not a primitive type (e.g. int)? I mean, in the data field of node, I should store the value itself or the address?

Comment: Always store the address (because you cannot make a difference in a simple data type or a pointer/structure data type). So if you want to pass an int value (e.g. 2), do not pass 2, but create an integer (malloc it), and pass it as a pointer which stores the pointer (pointing to 2) in the stack.

Comment: If i write this: node->data = &data, what happens? Can I store in node->data without creating other variables or pointers?

Comment: If you use the & it means the address of the pointer (thus a pointer to a pointer). This will not be useful. If you omit the & you get the pointer itself, than you have to store the 'real' data somewhere else. If you use * you store the content, but since it is a void pointer you cannot use it, unless you change the type to int or a structure, but this is not wanted since it will be depending on the type. The only good way is to really pass the length of the data type, but you said the prototype should not change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited again my code. There is the top() function, that must return the top node of the stack. Is my code correct?

Comment: It is correct if it returns what you expect... Normally it's best to ask specific questions, like try it yourself, and if it does not return then correct item, ask specifically about that (hard to say without analyzing all variables statically myself). Even better: write unit tests!